# C# - Working with high resolution screenshots

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, drawing, ocr

I need to capture an area within my desktop. But I need this area to be very high resolution (like, at least few thousand's pixels horizontal, same goes for vertical). Is it possible to get a screen capture that has high density of pixels? How can I do this? I tried capturing the screen with some AutoIt script, and got some very good results (images that were 350MB big), now I would like to do the same using C#.

**Edit:**

I am doing my read/write of a .tif file like that, and it already loses most of the data:

```
using (Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(@"ScreenShot.tif")) //this file has 350MB
{
    using (Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(bitmap))
    {
        newBitmap.Save("TESTRES.TIF", ImageFormat.Tiff); //now this file has about 60MB, Why?
    }
}
```

I am trying to capture my screen like that, but the best I can get from this is few megabytes (nowhere near 350MB):

```
using (var bmpScreenCapture = new Bitmap(window[2], window[3], PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
{
    using (var i = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenCapture))
    {
        i.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;

        i.CopyFromScreen(window[0], window[1], 0, 0, bmpScreenCapture.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
    }
    bmpScreenCapture.Save("test2.tif", ImageFormat.Tiff);
}
```

Comment: Do you want to get the picture of higher resolution than the screen's  resolution?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: I think so... When I capture a screen with AutoIt, it looks like pixel density in the captured screen is much higher than actual screen resolution. And I want the same effect in C# (basically I want to get image with as much data as possible - my goal is to get an image that weights 350MB (I need a lot of data in my image for OCR reasons))

Comment: You can't gather information more than the source has.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: I disagree. I already did it with AutoIt script (with three functions - `_ScreenCapture_Capture()`, `_GDIPlus_BitmapCreateFromHBITMAP()`, and `_WinAPI_CreateCompatibleBitmap()`). The result was very detailed, 350MB screenshot (and my monitor is only 1920x1080). Now, even if I tried to load this image in C#, when saved again, it had only 10% of the original size. So my question is, how to deal with such large images in C# without losing most of the data.

Comment: Do you hear about image formats at all? There are some formats which supports compression. Do you hear about that also?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: Dude, I know that I should use PNG/TIFF for that, and not to compress anything. But as I see it, you are telling me, that, what I want to achieve is impossible, while I already achieved it in AutoIt. Now I need to do it in C#. And yes, I don't know much about this stuff. If I knew everything, I wouldn't be asking on a forum.

Comment: You may want to look at the resolution of your 350MB file: It should be 19020x1080, or else it isn't a screenshot. What file format does it have? And which format did the 10% size version have?

Comment: @TaW: I am working on `Tiff`'s only. Basically I imported 350MB one into bitmap, and then saved this bitmap as .tif, and the saved one was much smaller than the original - so there was some data loss, I don't know why.

Comment: Not necessarily. Tif has many subformats, most of them with compressions, most of these __non-lossy__. So if the original was uncompressed and the 2nd version LZW compressed it will be a lot smaller but __without any data loss__!

Comment: `new Bitmap(bitmap)` will produce a 96-DPI bitmap, effectively lowering the original image DPI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't gather more information than the source has.**

This is a basic truth and it does apply here, too.
So you can't capture more the your 1920x1080 pixels at their color depth.

OTOH, since you want to feed the captured image into OCR, there a few more things to consider and in fact to do..

OCR is very happy if you help it by optimizing the image. This should involve

- reducing colors and adding contrast
- enlarging to the recommended dpi resolution
- adding even more contrast

Funnily, this will help OCR although the real information cannot increase above the original source. But a good resizing algorithm will add *invented* data and these often will be just what the OCR software needs.

You should also take care to use a good i.e. non lossy format when you store the image to a file like `png` or `tif` and never `jpg`.

The best way will have to be adjusted by trial and error until the OCR results are good enough.

Hint: Due to font antialiasing most text on screenshots is surrounded by a halo of colorful pixels. Getting rid of it by the reducing or even removing saturation is one way; maybe you want to turn it off in your display properties? (Check out `ClearType`!)

Comment: I already did what you said (http://i.stack.imgur.com/TtWC9.png - and this is my result). But I did everything in C#, and as far as I can see, my result is too low res (or dpi?) - OCR cannot see anything in there. So I need to start with a picture with greater quality, but I don't know how to obtain such in c#

Comment: FreeOCR by R. Richardson, using the Tesseract library, spits out this when feeding in your png: 

_Palladium lnlaid Breastplate
D
Buy Nmvfor: 60  
Sturdy Steel Gauntlets
Buy Nmvfor: 10 B3 $3
Cobalt Hardened Com bat Boots
Buy Nmvfor: 10
Quality Steel Pauldrons
D
B|.|yNmvfor: 30
Breastplate cfthe Hammer
D
B|.|yNmvfor: 310 96 S0
Type lll Titanium Weave Gauntlets
D
B|.|yNmvfor: 10 49
Platinum Protcmcrph Plastron_


This is not bad, considering the input. Usually traing will improve the result a lot..

Comment: What software are you using? Did you mean FreeOCR from www.paperfile.net ? Because I was using tesseract on this image, and it didn't recognize anything in there.

Comment: I got it [here](http://freeocr.giga.de/), a german site. They say that there are three programms of the same name, and yes it seems to be the same. I didn't do __anything__ at all, just saved you png, opened it and pressed OCR. Go figure.. It is version 5.02.